# Ask for suggestions on bilevel optimization question

Tags: bilevel-optimization

Here is a bilevel question:

the master problem is $\max_y \sum_{n \in 1,...,N} x[n] * y[n];$

subject to $$\min_x \sum_{n \in 1,...,N} x[n] * y[n]$$
$$yy^T = I$$
and some other linear constraints.

So it should be a bi-level question, with lower linear and higher quadratic.

**Question here.**

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: max sum{n in 1...N} x[n]*y[n]
s.t. y[n]*y[n]^T = I (regularization condition)
     x[n] = arg min x[n]*y[n]
     s.t. some linear constrains

Comment: Welcome to OR.SE! Please edit your question and rewrite your equations with [MathJax](https://or.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5/how-do-i-use-mathjax-on-this-site) to make it more readable. Also as @YukiJ mentioned, provide additional details to make your question clearer.

Comment: Did i rephrase the question correctly? I think $y*y^T = I $ implies that $\forall n: y_n = 1$. Is that what you mean? What is your question? You defined a problem but that problem isn't a question on it's own ...

Answer (score 4):

Some tools provide facilities for specifying and solving bilevel optimization problems. GAMS and Pyomo come to mind. See e.g. [Modeling Bilevel Programs in Pyomo](https://www.osti.gov/servlets/purl/1526125).

Otherwise, a standard approach for continuous bilevel problems is to formulate the first-order (or KKT) conditions for the inner problem and add these as constraints to the outer problem. It is always a good exercise to try this formulation. The optimality conditions for a linear inner problem lead to non-convex quadratic constraints. Global quadratic solvers can be used to solve this. As your outer problem is also non-convex quadratic, it may not be worthwhile to linearize the inner problem.

Integer bilevel problems are much more difficult. Sometimes Benders Decomposition is used for such models.

A standard reference on bilevel optimization is [Bard](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-1-4757-2836-1)

---

I see that a bit of a strange edit has been made to the original post. The added constraint containing an outer-product $$yy^T = I$$ will make the problem **infeasible**. Written differently: $$ y_iy_j = \begin{cases} 1 & \text{if $i=j$} \\ 0 & \text{if $i \ne j$}\end{cases}$$ The diagonal implies $y_i=\pm 1$, but that makes the off-diagonal products infeasible.